# How to 'scroll down' when there's nothing more to show? (cause I like the blank space)

Tags: text-editor, textmate, text, text-input, textedit

When I'm working in a text document, I like to start typing at the top of the window or in the middle. I hate when the carat/cursor gets all the way to the bottom and there's no blank space left underneath where my typing will appear. It's especially annoying when I'm adding to the document by drag&drop of outside text - much easier when your target is half a page/screen, not a 5mm line.

So is there any way to push the 'last line' up the screen and create blank space? eg. in TextEdit or Textmate or Coda or a similar app.

Comment: Press return a few times?

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot to say - that doesn't work too well for drag and drop purposes, cause then you have to carefully aim the drop at the next line, rather than just anywhere in the blank space.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a neat way of doing this.  I normally hit Command + down arrow.  This will bring me to the end of the page, where I can then press enter a few times, or if using textmate, you can create a snippet to insert carriage returns for you.  With an application like textexpander you can program a keypress to add carriage returns for you.

Answer (score 2):

BBEdit by Bare Bones Software allows for extra space with with two settings: half-page or full-page. You mention TextMate specifically, but it doesn't allow for extra space by default, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs.app is the only editor I'm aware of that gives you extra space beyond the end of a text document.  You can scroll the last line of a document all the way to the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Sublime Text 2 today, and it behaves exactly the way I want.

It's a great editor in general, too. One of the very best.